# Beautiful Soup and searching in results

Tags: python, search, beautifulsoup

These are my first steps with python, please bear with me.

Basically I want to parse a Table of Contents from a single Dokuwiki page with Beautiful Soup. The TOC looks like this:

```
<div id="dw__toc">
<h3 class="toggle">Table of Contents</h3>
<div>

<ul class="toc">
<li class="level1"><div class="li"><a href="#section">#</a></div>
<ul class="toc">
<li class="level2"><div class="li"><a href="#link1">One</a></div></li>
<li class="level2"><div class="li"><a href="#link2">Two</a></div></li>
<li class="level2"><div class="li"><a href="#link3">Three</a></div></li>
```

I would like to be able to search in the content of the a-tags and if a result is found return its content and also return the href-link. So if I search for "one" the result should be

```
One
#link1
```

What I have done so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2


#Grab and open URL, create BeatifulSoup object
url = "http://www.somewiki.at/wiki/doku.php"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
#Grab Table of Contents
grab_toc = soup.find('div', {"id":"dw__toc"})

#Look for all divs with class: li
ftext = grab_toc.findAll('div', {"class":"li"})
#Look for links
links = grab_toc.findAll('a',href=True)

#Iterate
for everytext in ftext:
    text = ''.join(everytext.findAll(text=True))
    data = text.strip()
    print data

for everylink in links:
    print everylink['href']
```

This prints out the data I want but I'm kind of lost to rewrite it to be able to search within the result and only return the searchterm. Tried something like

```
if data == 'searchtearm':
        print data
        break
else:
        print 'Nothing found'
```

But this is kind of a weak search. Is there a nicer way to do this? In my example the Beatiful Soup resultset is changed into a list. Is it better to search in the result set in the first place, if so then how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of searching through the links one-by-one, have BeautifulSoup search for you, using a regular expression:

```
import re

matching_link = grab_toc.find('a', text=re.compile('one', re.IGNORECASE))
```

This would find the *first* `a` link in the table of contents with the 3 characters `one` in the text somewhere. Then just print the link and text:

```
print matching_link.string
print matching_link['href']
```

Short demo based on your sample:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import re
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('''\
... <div id="dw__toc">
... <h3 class="toggle">Table of Contents</h3>
... <div>
... 
... <ul class="toc">
... <li class="level1"><div class="li"><a href="#section">#</a></div>
... <ul class="toc">
... <li class="level2"><div class="li"><a href="#link1">One</a></div></li>
... <li class="level2"><div class="li"><a href="#link2">Two</a></div></li>
... <li class="level2"><div class="li"><a href="#link3">Three</a></div></li>
... </ul></ul>''')
>>> matching_link = soup.find('a', text=re.compile('one', re.IGNORECASE))
>>> print matching_link.string
One
>>> print matching_link['href']
#link1
```

In BeautifulSoup version 3, the above `.find()` call returns the contained `NavigableString` object instead. To get back to the parent `a` element, use the `.parent` attribute:

```
matching_link = grab_toc.find('a', text=re.compile('one', re.IGNORECASE)).parent
print matching_link.string
print matching_link['href']
```

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I'm looking for! I had to change `re.IGNORE` to `re.IGNORECASE` and it works for the text. For the links I get: `print matching_link['href']
TypeError: string indices must be integers`. That's because `matching_link` is a string, right? How can I avoid this? Thx in advance!

Comment: @duenni: `matching_link` in *my* example is still the matched element , a BeautifulSoup `Tag` object. I certainly didn't reassign `matching_link.string` to it. :-) Apologies for the `re.IGNORE` mixup, I just normally use the `re.I` shorthand version.

Comment: Mhh it doesn't work for the links. It alway complains with `string indices must be integers` even if I `for x in matching_link: print x['href']`. Why does it work for you? Sorry for the dumb questions.

Comment: @duenni: ah, but `matching_link` is *one* match, a `Tag`, not a list of them. That is because I used `.find()`; use `.find_all()` if you want to find *more* than one.

Comment: `print matching_link.string` returns `One`. Works for me. In your example print `matching_link['href']` returns `#link1` but not for me. How do you get to the corresponding link? `matching_link` only contains `One` and not the href (because of the regex). But you also get the href-link in your example, this confuses me. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @duenni: `.find()` returns a `Tag` object, and it's that object that has a `.string` attribute. It also acts as a dictionary; see what `matching_object.attrs` holds (it returns a python dictionary) to see what attributes are defined.

Comment: `print type(matching_link)` -> `<class 'BeautifulSoup.NavigableString'>`. Tried it with the real URL and it has spaces in the a-Tags, so I'm getting a NavigableString instead of a Tag. Sorry, didn't knew that.

Comment: @duenni: ah, I think you are using BeautifulSoup 3, I am using version 4 (much improved). Any reason you stick with 3? And you found the contained text, not the parent `a` tag, my `.find()` specifically looked for an `'a'` tag with `.find('a', text=...)`.

Comment: @duenni: Trying this out on BeautifulSoup 3 indeed returns the contained `NavigableString` object, not the parent link. I consider that a bug in the API, you can get the link with `matching_link.parent`

Comment: Ahhhhh. `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` imports BeatifulSoup 3. I changed it to `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` and everything works like expected. Many thanks! If I could double vote your answer I would. Your help is greatly appreciated!